# I want to call the ajax value and pass it as a parameter of the action link.I need to pass the selectedValue in the new right after langID=

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $("#pageid").change(function () { 
        $.ajax({               
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',                
            data: { langID: $('#pageid').val() },
            selectedValue: $(this).val(),              
            success: function (result) {            
              $('#visualization').load('@Url.Action("MyAction", "Dashboard", new {langID=})').html(data.toString); 
            },
            error: function () {
             alert('Error');
            }           
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace value in following way.

```
var param = $('#pageid').val();
var url = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "Dashboard", new { langID= "__param__" })'; 
 $('#visualization').load(url.replace('__param__', encodeURIComponent(param)))
```